# normal map not applying correctly

Tags: glsl, shader

I am currently trying to apply a normal map in my shader but the shading in the final image is [way off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIdSI.jpg).

[image]

Surfaces that should be shaded are completely bright, surfaces that should be bright are completely shaded and the top surface, which should have the same shade regardless of rotation of the y-axis, is alternating between bright and dark.

After some trial and error i found out that i can get the correct shading by changing this

```c
vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize((normal_color.xyz * 2.0) - 1.0);
```

to this

```c
vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
```

Diffuse and specular lighting are now working [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWzD0.jpg),

[image]

but obviously without the normal map applied. I honestly have no idea where exactly the error is originating. I am quite new to shader programming and was following [this](https://shader-tutorial.dev/intermediates/normal-mapping/) tutorial. Below are the shader sources, with all irrelevant parts cut.

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 tangent;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 bitangent;
layout(location = 4) in vec2 texture_coordinates;

layout(location = 0) out mat3 normal_matrix;
layout(location = 3) out vec2 texture_coordinates_out;
layout(location = 4) out vec4 vertex_position_viewspace;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform Matrices {
    mat4 world;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 projection;
} uniforms;

void main() {

    mat4 worldview = uniforms.view * uniforms.world;

    normal_matrix = mat3(worldview) * mat3(normalize(tangent), normalize(bitangent), normalize(normal));
    
    vec4 vertex_position_worldspace = uniforms.world * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vertex_position_viewspace = uniforms.view * vertex_position_worldspace;

    gl_Position = uniforms.projection * vertex_position_viewspace;
    texture_coordinates_out = texture_coordinates;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in mat3 normal_matrix;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 texture_coordinates;
layout(location = 4) in vec4 vertex_position_viewspace;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragment_color;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform Matrices {
    mat4 world;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 projection;
} uniforms;

// ...
layout (set = 0, binding = 2) uniform sampler2D normal_map;
// ...

const vec4 LIGHT = vec4(1.25, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0);

void main() {

    // ...
    vec4 normal_color = texture(normal_map, texture_coordinates);
    // ...

    vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize((normal_color.xyz * 2.0) - 1.0);

    vec4 light_position_viewspace = uniforms.view * LIGHT;
    vec3 light_direction_viewspace = normalize((light_position_viewspace - vertex_position_viewspace).xyz);
    vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(vertex_position_viewspace.xyz);

    vec3 light_color_intensity = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * 7.0;
    float distance_from_light = distance(vertex_position_viewspace, light_position_viewspace);

    float diffuse_strength = clamp(dot(normal_viewspace, light_direction_viewspace), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 diffuse_light = (light_color_intensity * diffuse_strength) / (distance_from_light * distance_from_light);

    // ...
    fragment_color.rgb = (diffuse_color.rgb * diffuse_light);
    fragment_color.a = diffuse_color.a;
}
```

There are some things i am a bit uncertain about. For example i noticed that in the tutorial, the light is called `lightPosition_worldSpace`, making me think i need to multiply the light by the world matrix first, but doing so only makes my light rotate with the cube and still doesn't fix my lighting issue.

Any help or ideas on what i could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `vec3(0.0, 3.5, 3.5)`? The position of the camera in view space is (0, 0, 0). Is `view_direction_viewspace` the vector form the camera to the fragment or the vector form the fragment to the camera? Try `vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(vertex_position_viewspace.xyz);` or `vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(-vertex_position_viewspace.xyz)`

Comment: Yes, it's the position of the camera. In the tutorial the code was `- vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` and that really confused me into thinking it was the camera position in world space. I fixed it now and it does look better (or maybe i'm just imagining) but the shading is still wrong sadly. I will edit my question to include this comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the one who created the tutorial site you're referencing.

If possible could you share a link to your normal map as well? When you say that when you changed the line where the normal of the fragment is calculated using the normal map from this

```
vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize((normal_color.xyz * 2.0) - 1.0);
```

to one where you hardcode a value like this

```
vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
```

and that fixes the rendering issue, it seems to indicate an issue with the normal map itself.

One way to verify this is to set your entire normal map image to the RGB value `(128, 128, 255)`, which is exactly the same as the `vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` value you were using in your changed line. If this results in the object rendering correctly the same as when you were using a hardcoded value, that means you were using a bad normal map.

The normal map is just a texture/image that stores the directions of the normals of your object in "tangent-space" (think of it as like if you had to flatten out your entire object into a 2D surface, and then the normals for each point of that surface is plotted on the map). For each pixel, the red channel represents the X-axis, the green channel represents the Y-axis, and the blue channel represents the Z-axis.

With colors, the range of colors in a normal map goes from `(0, 0, 128)` to `(255, 255, 255)` (for images where each color channel uses 8 bits/1 byte), but in GLSL this would be a range from `(0.0, 0.0, 0.5)` to `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`. Let's just work with the range that is used in GLSL for the sake of simplicity.

When looking at the actual possible values for normals, their range actually is `(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)` to `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` because you can have a normal direction be either forwards or backwards in either the X-axis or Y-axis.

So when we have a color value of `(0.0, 0.0, 0.5)`, we're actually talking about a normal direction vector `(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)`. Similarly, a color value of `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` means the normal direction vector `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, and a color value of `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` means a normal value of `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`.

So the goal now becomes transforming the value from the normal map from the color value range (`(0.0, 0.0, 0.5)` to `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`) to the actual range for normals (`(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)` to `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`).

If you multiply a value from a normal map by 2.0, you change the possible range of the value from `(0.0, 0.0, 0.5)` - `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` to `(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` - `(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)`. And then if you subtract 1.0 from the result, the range now changes from `(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` - `(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)` to `(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)` - `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`, which is exactly the possible range of the normals of an object.

So you have to make sure that when you're creating your normal map, the range of the RGB color values is between `(0, 0, 128)` - `(255, 255, 255)`.

Side note: As for why the range of the blue channel (Z-axis) in the normal map can only be between 128 to 255, a value less than 128 means that a negative value on the Z-axis, meaning that the normal of the fragment is pointing into the surface, not out of it. Since a normal map is supposed to represent the values of the normals when the surface of the object is flattened and facing towards you, having a normal with a negative Z-axis value would mean that at that point the surface is actually facing away from you, which doesn't really make sense, hence why negative values are not allowed.

You could still try having the blue channel be a value less than 128 and see what interesting results pop out.

Also with regards to the doubt you mentioned in the end and in the comments:

1. What does `lightPosition_worldSpace` mean?

`lightPosition_worldSpace` represents the coordinate at which light is present relative to the center of the world (relative to the entire world you're rendering), hence the world-space suffix. You just need to multiply this position with the your view-matrix if you wish to know the position of the light is view-space (relative to your camera).

If you have a coordinate that is relative to the center of the object you're rendering, then you should multiply it with your model matrix (`uniforms.world`) to transform that coordinate from one that's relative to the center of your model to one that's relative to the center of the world. Since the `lightPosition_worldSpace` is the position of the light already relative to the center of the world, you don't need to multiply them. This is why you saw the behavior of the light moving with the cube when you did try to do so (the light was moved since its coordinates were thought to be placed relative to the cube itself).

2. Your comment regarding confusion with the line `vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(vertex_position_viewspace.xyz - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));`

This is bad on my part for not representing what `vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` is with a variable. This is supposed to represent the position of the camera in view-space. Since in view-space the camera is at the center, its coordinate is `vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`.

As for why I'm doing

```
vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(vertex_position_viewspace.xyz - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

when

```
vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(vertex_position_viewspace.xyz);
```

is simpler and is basically the same thing, I had written it so to make it more obvious what was happening (which it appears I failed to do).

Typically, when you have two coordinates and you want to find the direction from a source coordinate to a destination coordinate you subtract the two coordinates to get their direction + magnitude. By normalizing that difference, you then just the directional component, with the magnitude part removed. So the equation for finding a direction from a source coordinate to a destination coordinate becomes:

```
direction = normalize(destination coordinate - source coordinate)
```

`view_direction_viewspace` Is supposed to represent the direction from the camera towards the fragment. To calculate this, we can just subtract the position of the camera (`vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`) from the position of the fragment (`vertex_position_viewspace.xyz`) and then run `normalize(...)` on the difference to get that result.

I've generally tried to maintain this consistency where when I'm calculating a direction using two coordinates I always have a destination and source coordinate explicitly written out, hence why you see the line `vec3 view_direction_viewspace = normalize(vertex_position_viewspace.xyz - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));` in the fragment shader code.

I've updated the code by setting `vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` to a variable `cameraPosition_viewSpace` and using that to better clarify this intention.

Feel free to reach out through [GitHub issues](https://github.com/sabarnac/shader-tutorial/issues) if you want to ask anything else or help improve the tutorial.

Comment: Okay wow, first of all, thank you for giving me that much of a response. I did eventually get it working by plugging in values for the red and green channel until the cube was black (so properly mapped to 0). The resulting code looks like this `vec3 normal_tangentspace = normalize(normal_color.xyz * vec3(2.0, 2.0, 1.0) - vec3(0.4, 0.4, 0.0));`. It works, but even now i don't really understand why. I did check my normal maps in advance (and again just now), the color for a front facing normal is `128, 128, 255`, which seems fine to me. I think i might have to do some more investigating later :)

Comment: You can share your diffuse and normal map images in your question, that would help us try to re-create the issue and better figure out the reason why it's not working.

Comment: The normal map i used for that cube looks like this: https://imgur.com/2WXIC9r

Comment: Your normal map definitely appears to be abnormal in certain spots. As you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/mJL7AIS.png), there are spots where the blue color of the pixels of your normal map drops below 128, which isn't allowed. If you look at [this normal map example from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Normal_map_example_with_scene_and_result.png) you'll see that the blue color never drops below 128 for any pixel.

Also, try using a completely flat normal map [like this](https://i.imgur.com/XxWF1Ye.png) and see if this works with the original code.

Comment: That's interesting, i did not notice that. I did try it with a completely flat map but ended up with the same result, so the main problem seems to be something unrelated to those abnormalities.

Comment: Hmm, having the line as `vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize((normal_color.xyz * 2.0) - 1.0);` and using a flat normal map should be equivalent to the line you changed it to (`vec3 normal_viewspace = normal_matrix * normalize(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));`). This seems to indicate an issue with maybe how the normal map is being read/stored?

Could you try setting the output of the fragment shader (`fragment_color.rgb`) to the sampled color value from the normal map (`normal_color.xyz`) and verify that the normal map renders onto the cube as expected? You can share a screenshot as well

Comment: As for your normal map working with the line `vec3 normal_tangentspace = normalize(normal_color.xyz * vec3(2.0, 2.0, 1.0) - vec3(0.4, 0.4, 0.0));`. Since the range of each coordinate of `normal_color` is (0 - 1, 0 - 1, 0 - 1), multiplying it by `vec3(2.0, 2.0, 1.0)` changes the range to (0 - 2, 0 - 2, 0 - 1). Subtracting `vec3(0.4, 0.4, 0.0)` from it will create a final range of (-0.4 -1.6, -0.4 -1.6, 0 - 1). Since you're converting it to a unit vector using `normalize`, the final vector having a value greater than 1 on any axis gets fixed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't updated this post in a while because i have completely shifted away from using normal mapping (for now) but still wanted to post an answer, in case that someone else runs into the same problem. I still can't be 100% sure but i am fairly certain, that this behavior was caused by the library i was using to load the normal map. Special thanks to sabarnac who has been a huge help to me in solving this.